# Turning on developer options of Collector for ArcGIS on Android (Early Release)?

Tags: arcgis-collector, logging

I am trying to turn on logging in order to troubleshoot an issue.

And found this is on [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/229193-problem-downloading-offline-area-in-new-collector-but-not-collector-classic):

> Open the settings > tap your login name at the top 3 times >
>   "Developer" options should appear at the bottom of the settings > Open
>   the Developer options and turn on logging > reproduce the download
>   failure > back in the Developer options, click Logs > you will see
>   more detailed errors that you can review or share out via email, etc.

I don't know what device or version is referenced in the above-mentioned post but I don't have Settings. I did go into the About screen and started trip tapping things.  And I did get a developer options enabled notification message, but no actual UI change or additional options appeared.  And I'm not really sure what was actually being tapped that triggered that message.

How do you turn on the developer options?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I just did the same.  on the new version of collector, you go to settings and tap three times on you name and then exit out of settings and when you go into settings next time the developer option is right at the very bottom.  In there are the log settings that you need.

Comment: When I do this, the only options available in the Developer Screen is "Placeholder"? any ideas why?

Comment: Same thing for me.